# pip installation with no internet access

Tags: python, offline

I want to setup python with modules on a computer without access to the internet.

I've created the requirements list with freeze on a computer with the same python and pip version connected to the internet, downloaded the packages and transferred it to the offline computer. Now I'm trying to install them but I'm having some difficulties. They're both windows machines. Please advise, thanks in advance.

```
PS C:\Users\pulcma\pip> dir


    Directory: C:\Users\pulcma\pip


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         2/1/2024   2:53 PM                pip
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM         158340 bcrypt-4.1.2-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM           3439 caugetch-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM         181358 cffi-1.16.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM           1713 clipboard-0.0.4.tar.gz
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM          25335 colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM        2882354 cryptography-42.0.2-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM         840896 future-0.18.3.tar.gz
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM           8683 getpass4-0.0.14.1-py3-none-any.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM         219198 netmiko-4.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM         416752 ntc_templates-4.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM         225900 paramiko-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   1:27 PM        2109393 pip-23.3.2-py3-none-any.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM         118697 pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM         212141 PyNaCl-1.5.0-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM          20920 pyperclip-1.8.2.tar.gz
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM          90585 pyserial-3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM         157350 PyYAML-6.0.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:54 PM            630 requirements.txt
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM           8653 scp-0.14.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:37 PM         575457 setuptools-40.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:52 PM         576332 setuptools-41.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM          11053 six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-a----         2/1/2024   2:17 PM          44664 textfsm-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl


PS C:\Users\pulcma\pip> pip install -r requirements.txt --find-links=C:\Users\pulcma\pip --no-index
Looking in links: c:\Users\pulcma\pip
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\bcrypt-4.1.2-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\caugetch-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\cffi-1.16.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\cryptography-42.0.2-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\netmiko-4.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\ntc_templates-4.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\paramiko-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\pynacl-1.5.0-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\pyserial-3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\pyyaml-6.0.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\scp-0.14.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\textfsm-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\clipboard-0.0.4.tar.gz (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      Looking in links: c:\Users\pulcma\pip
      Processing c:\users\pulcma\pip\setuptools-41.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
PS C:\Users\pulcma\pip>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must download the wheel package on your online pc

```
pip download wheel
```

Then transfer the file on your offline pc  and installing it

```
pip install yourwheelpackagename.whl
```

Then the installation must work

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --find-links=C:\Users\pulcma\pip --no-index
```